# Python Package with Sub-Packages for Microservice purpose

Tags: python, pip, microservices

Im currently refactoring my monolith into microserivces. To make them communicate each service has as client module with client in it that call per request the other services. I want to manage the different packages as easy as possible so I created a repository which is my package. Then each folder/module is the service with the modules of it that are needed.

What I want to achieve is that I can simply call `pip install package["subpackage"]` and it installs only that specific module of the package. I choose a big package over small packages because of the naming problem that most services have basic names where pip packages already exist with these names.

Repository of package

repo

- payments/
  client/
  models/
- auth/
  client/
  models/

setup.py

Is there a way to provide the information what each submodule / module needs for installing like install_requires for each module ?

Is there a other good approach that I should take ? I know some companies to it with java so that each module is its own "package" but they are all under a company package. Maybe in python there is a better solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add additional requirements using:

```
setup(
    name="package",
    version=__version__,
    install_requires=["stuff", "every", "package", "needs"],
    extras_require={
        "subpackage": ["dependency_1", "dependency_2"]
    }
)
```

You can then run

```
pip install package[subpackage]
```

To install the extra dependencies.

In my organization, we

1. Split each server into their own repositories
2. Have a 'mono repo' that has all of the servers as git submodules
3. Make each server pip-installable with an internal pip server
4. Have a deployment repo that pins the versions of the servers we are using, as well as all the deployment scripts such as pushing docker contianers to local testing environments and terraform scripts to deploy to AWS.

Comment: Is it normal that when I modules in a package and I install the package that each module is its own folder in lib in a venv ?

Comment: @KevinRump I am not sure what you mean, you will need to elaborate

Comment: So I have this folder structure from above, when I then install my package with all submodules I expect a folder in the lib of the venv called my package and in the folder there should be all modules right ? But when I install it, my modules of the package are all in seperate folders

Comment: @KevinRump Are you trying to make all of your servers into one single package?

Comment: Just the clients of each service, so I can just install package["service1"] and have the client of that installed

Comment: @KevinRump, You could do `extras_requires: {'service1': ['service1==1.1.1']}` and set `install_requires=[]` but then I dont kow why you wouldnt just do `pip install service1` instead, or in service1 do `pip install service1[client]`

Comment: They have really basic names a.e Authorization and this package is a public package that already exists and I wasnt able to add extra index url to install_requires of packages

Comment: @KevinRump Hard to say what the best way to implement this is without more knowledge of how it works. Doing `extra_requires` with all the dependencies of the clients should install all the dependencies those clients need. FYI when you do extra requires, you need to wrap your extra-imports in `try: except ImportError`

Comment: I can give you some more information, I have different microservices and for the communication of the services I wanted to use simple written clients that call the service per request and automatilcy provide authorization stuff and so on. To use these clients each service should be a package that is installable, problem was that I came to the problem where naming needs to be unique, so my idea was to create a main package containing all the clients for the microservices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251935/discussion-between-tom-mclean-and-kevin-rump).